# How prove this inequality $\frac{2n^2+1}{3n}\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a(k)}{k}\le\frac{2n(n+3)}{3(n+1)}$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

**Question:**

> For a positive integer $k$, let $a(k)$ be the largest odd divisor of $k$,

show that :

> for each positive integer $n$, 
>   $$\dfrac{2n^2+1}{3n}\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{a(k)}{k}\le\dfrac{2n(n+3)}{3(n+1)}$$

I found this problem is similar this Monthly problem:http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM11553.pdf

I use this result can't prove my inequality.

Thank you

Comment: Something similar to the upper bound is proven in the link. I believe that they proved something stronger, but haven't worked through the details

Comment: @CalvinLin,I found my inequality is stronger this AMM problem

Comment: Completely solved in http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2295v1

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac {a (k)} {k} = \sum_{k = 1}^{[n/2]} \frac {a (2k)} {2k} + \sum_{k = 1}^{[(n + 1)/2]} \frac {a (2k - 1)} {2k - 1} \leqslant \frac {[n/2]} {2} + [(n + 1)/2]$$
if you include an integer itself as its divisor.